# Using Jacoco in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, jacoco

I am using eclipse with Buildship plugin. I have a gradle project in it with build.gradle as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

The project just is to understand how should I do Unit testing. I want to use this plugin jacoco which is a code coverage tool. Following is the command :

```
gradle clean test jacocoTestReport
```

Now, I need a console to write this.

How should I write this command in eclipse?
OR
Is there a alternative GUI way for this in eclipse + Builship Plugin ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to see coverage in Eclipse is to install the [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) plugin which uses JaCoCo under the hood. Then you can

1. Right click on a test class / test method
2. Coverage as...
3. JUnit test

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me you added the apply statement to your build script and then clicked the refresh button in your gradle tasks view, but didn't see the 'jacocoTestReport' task show up. This appears to be because it doesn't declare itself to be in a group. (I.e. one of build, build setup, documentation, help, upload, or verification.) I added the following to my script and refreshed again, and the jacoco task then appeared under verification.

```
task jacoco(group: 'verification', dependsOn: jacocoTestReport) {
}
```